# What does "a flute busting" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

I was watching an ERB video and heard a phrase "a flute busting Prussian"

See *Alexander the Great vs Ivan the Terrible - Epic Rap Battles of History* at (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVbH1BVXywY ,1:46)

I suppose it means something like "one who is blowing a flute" but I'm not sure if there's another slang meaning or something else.

Comment: The only other association I might make is one who destroys the fluted columns in Roman-style buildings.  Ie, a vicious warrior.

Comment: "Frederick the Great himself is known to have composed 121 flute sonatas, ..." http://www.hoasm.org/XIB/XIBCourtFrederickGreat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video is explained at [epicrapbattlesofhistory.wikia.com](http://epicrapbattlesofhistory.wikia.com/wiki/Alexander_the_Great_vs_Ivan_the_Terrible/Rap_Meanings).

> Frederick the Great:
>
> **(Psst!) What about a flute-busting Prussian?**
>
> *(Frederick the Great enters, a shadow at first, to offer that perhaps he could defeat Ivan. Frederick the Great was a "Great" leader of Prussia who was prolific with the flute.).*
>
> **(Old Fritz! Old Fritz! Old Fritz! Old Fritz! Old Fritz! Old Fritz! Old Fritz! Old Fritz!).**
>
> *(Frederick builds up his verse with a flute solo as a series of voices chant his nickname, Old Fritz, derived from the affectionate nickname, Der Alte Fritz, given to him by the Prussians.).*

I suspect that  *flute-busting Prussian*  simply sounded better than *flute-playing Prussian* !
Hard to be sure which of the multitude of slang  meanings of *busting*  is meant, some options  from UD :

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bust e.g

> 2. To shoot a gun.
> 3. To rap.
> 4. Punch someone ..

Answer (score 0):

As it is a rap video the rap use of [busting](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=busting%20a%20move) is obviously intended. Although it's normally used to describe flamboyant dancing as in "busting some moves" (or "shapes" in the UK) "flute busting Prussian" is obviously meant to convey the meaning of "a Prussian who habitually plays the flute in an impressive, flamboyant, and probably rapid way".

Being from a rap the quote falls into the category of poetry or lyric so the meaning is not necessarily part of accepted usage in its entirety although it does carry its meaning succinctly, effectively and humourously.